# Кликабельные ссылки в QWebEngineView

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть ли способы реализации данной функции в Pyqt5?

Answer (score 3):

[Минимальный пример](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-minimal-main-cpp.html) из официальной qt документации уже "кликабельные" ссылки создаёт:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Usage: view-url [<url>]"""
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QWebEngineView()
url = QUrl(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'https://www.qt.io')
view.setUrl(url)
view.resize(1024, 750)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Чтобы исправить чёрное окно при запуске, на моей Ubuntu машине пришлось [добавить перед импортами](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9199#issuecomment-383842265):

```
import ctypes
ctypes.CDLL("libGL.so.1", mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
```

Левый клик на ссылке прекрасно работает:

[image: screencast qtwebengineview]

Версии:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR

print(sys.version)
print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
print("SIP version:", SIP_VERSION_STR)
print("PyQt version:", PYQT_VERSION_STR)
```

Результат на моей машине:

```
3.6.3 (default, Nov  7 2017, 14:24:06) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Qt version: 5.10.0
SIP version: 4.19.7
PyQt version: 5.10
```

Comment: Скорей всего не так поставил вопрос, хотел бы сделать как в стандартном браузер лкм переходить открыть ссылку в этом окне, в данный момент это происходит с помощью пкм - follow link.

Comment: @santos_q: я не понимаю, что такое лкм, пкм. Вы хотите свой браузер написать и начать с добавления адресной строки в GUI или что-то другое?

Comment: Т.е например гугл выдал запрос и чтобы перейти на нужную страницу нужно нажать на правую кнопку мыши и выбрать Follow Link, а хотелось бы чтобы стандартно на левую кнопку. Может есть какие-нибудь параметры для этого? Или нужно улавливать событие клика на ссылку и затем ее подгружать?

Comment: @santos_q: ничего не надо делать, уже по нажатию на левую кнопку мыши над ссылкой происходит переход. Вы запустили код в ответе и левая кнопка мыши у вас не работает?

Comment: да, не работает

Comment: @jfs а какой движок использует браузер Qt? chrome?

Comment: @Twiss: [pyqt документация](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.html) говорит, что на основе Chromium (Blink? движок).

Comment: @jfs понятно, да в принципе сейчас почти все браузеры на нем) Можно было бы и не спрашивать)