# Сделать в tkinter фоном изображение с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Есть код:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 540, height = 540)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\popka.jpg"))
canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=img)
```

Который делает фоном изображение. Мне было бы удобнее напрямую указать ссылку на фото с сайта, например http://mypage.com/popka.jpg
Как это сделать без костылей и максимально лаконично?

Comment: у вас вопрос, есть ли в tkinter что-то вроде [QWebEngineView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828140/23044) или [как скачать картинку в Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859290/4279)?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку `urlib` для того чтобы использовать ссылку на ваше изображение

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=540, height=540)
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.name_file = "https://pp.userapi.com/c614930/v614930016/9ae5/GYv6dLqMD7w.jpg?ava=1"
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(urlopen(self.name_file)))
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

Comment: спасибо, потестим!